# JAX-RS: Can Marshal Fine But Unmarshalling Is Incorrect

Tags: java, service, jaxb, jax-rs

This is probably going to be a bit too open ended to get an answer but it's worth a shot.

I have a `JAX-RS` service I am calling.  The service itself creates an object called `"ServiceOverrideWrapper"` that it marshals into `JSON`. That gets sent over the wire & a client attempts to **unmarshall** that back to the same object.  But the trouble is that 
 the client doesn't have a full representation of what's sent across the wire.

Here's my ServiceOverrideWrapper:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({ User.class })
public class ServiceOverrideWrapper {
  private List<IUser> users = new ArrayList<IUser>();

  // Some methods removed for brevity

  @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
  public List<IUser> getUsers() {
    return users;
  }
}
```

The `IUser` interface & `User` class are simple POJO's containg String fields, each marked with `@XmlElement`.

Upon response from my client, a call to `getUsers()` results in a blank list when it should contain information.  Adding a `LogInInterceptor` does sound the inbound message as containing information:

```
{"serviceOverrideWrapper":{"user":[{"email":"someone@blah.com", ...}]}}
```

I'm getting no stack traces or anything to aid me into finding out what is going wrong.

Does anyone have any suggestions on things I can try.  A lot of `JAXB` seems to be not fantastically documented and I seem to be going on a lot of trial & error.

Comment: i've found jaxb to be fairly well documented compared to other projects.  This has been my fall back doc https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.5-2/docs/ch03.html

Have you tried actually stepping through your jaxrs webservice in your favourite ide?

Comment: I've not dived into the CXF code (which I am using to expose my service) but that's next on the list. Posting this while I dive into that as it's quite time consuming!  Cheers for the documentation link - I'll have a read of that too.

Comment: Another step i use to debug these problems is using a standalone rest client (postman for chrome is good).  If you aren't getting a result in postman you know the service is broken, if you are then your client is

Comment: I've been doing just that.  The service is fine, it's returning the JSON I expect. My standalone client also receives the JSON fine.  But something is going wrong from going from that JSON string to my Java object.

Comment: JAXB does not do object-to-JSON.  Many JAX-RS providers leverage JSON-binding providers based on JAXB metadata.  If you can reference the JSON-binding provider being used then it will be easier to solve the problem.

Comment: Right. JBoss 7.x has RestEasy as the JAX-RS implementation for example which leverages Jackson to do the mapping; I had to upgrade the RestEasy version (which also updates Jackson) before it would pick up certain JAXB annotations, as an example where it can go wrong.